# Popular questions requiring answers

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Some SE questions stand high in search engine rankings. This attracts traffic to SE, but such questions don't get attention from the community. Also, users from search engines typically don't vote. You won't find these questions on the front page.

This is the list of such questions ranked by the number of views divided by the number of answers.

### Most viewed questions with no answers

1. [Why is AC = MC in the monopoly?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6251/why-is-ac-mc-in-the-monopoly)
2. [Difference between embodied and commanded labor in the Labor Theory of Value?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/7026/difference-between-embodied-and-commanded-labor-in-the-labor-theory-of-value)
3. [Multiplier in the two-sector Keynesian model](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5835/multiplier-in-the-two-sector-keynesian-model)
4. [How does one calculate an optimal consumption bundle if the MRS only contains one variable?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10472/how-does-one-calculate-an-optimal-consumption-bundle-if-the-mrs-only-contains-on)
5. https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/what-are-the-limitations-of-economic-law

### Most viewed questions with no accepted answers

1. [What is the definition of exogenous and endogenous preferences](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4913)
2. [Partial vs. general equilibrium](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/75)
3. [How to calculate equilibrium income given a certain level of unemployment?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5638)
4. [What is the difference between intensive margin and extensive margin in labor economics?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/2941)
5. [Why is AC = MC in the monopoly?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6251)

### Full list of such questions

The list of all Econ.SE questions sorted by views-to-answers. You can adjust the number of lines by changing `top 25` to somethings like `top 100`:

- http://data.stackexchange.com/economics/query/558781/popular-questions-requiring-answers

I've made this list out of curiosity, but there're decent questions with several thousands of viewers. I hope it'll help prioritize things a bit.

Comment: Excellent post. I will start looking at the list and seeing if I can contribute some answer to these questions. others, such as "what are the limits of economic law?" should probably be deleted because we don't want people's first encounter with this site to be such low quality, closed posts.

Comment: @Ubiquitous If these posts got deleted, then people wouldn't find the site. They look for answers to such poor questions. Maybe they need to know why a question makes no sense.